# Is there a way I could pass more than a limited amount of arrays through a php function?

Tags: php, html, arrays, web

I have this function which basically passes different arrays but it can only pass arrays with a length of 5. I was wondering if there is a way to pass various array lengths through this function?

The output needs to only show one item at a time rather than all. I have 8 arrays with various lengths which is why I am making one general function to pass the arrays through.

```
function myFunction(&$array){
    //shuffling array contents
    shuffle($array);

    //isolate an array
    if(in_array($array[0], $array)){
        echo $array[0];
    }
    elseif(in_array($array[1], $array)){
        echo $array[1];
    }       
    elseif(in_array($array[2], $array)){
        echo $array[2];
    }
    elseif(in_array($array[3], $array)){
        echo $array[3];
    }
    elseif(in_array($array[4], $array)){
        echo $array[4];
    }
}
```

Comment: A **value** of 5, or a **length** of 5? There's a difference

Comment: How could something in the array not be in the array?

Comment: I'm also not sure why you're doing all that testing when a simple `foreach` would iterate all the values

Comment: if your are trying to find out how many items are in the array, then you need to use `count($your_array_to_get_count_of)`. And you should definitely do a for each with that to save lines of code.

Comment: It looks like this would always just echo the first array item. I think it would be easier to assist you with this if you provided a bit more explanation about what it's used for, and maybe some example input/output.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer! I meant the length of 5 and the reason I am doing it this way rather than a foreach is because I need each array to display one at a time during a refresh in page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I'm probably still missing something, but it looks like this could be simplified to:

```
function myFunction(&$array){
    //shuffling array contents
    shuffle($array);

    //isolate an array
    echo isset($array[0]) ? $array[0] : '';
}
```

Which would take arrays of any length (including zero), shuffle and echo one item.

Answer (score 0):

Add an argument to your function, e.g. `$len`, and use a loop:

```
function myFunction(&$array, $len){
    //shuffling array contents
    shuffle($array);

    //isolate an array
    for ($i = 0; $i < len; $i++) {
        if(in_array($array[i], $array)){
            echo $array[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This will do exactly the same as your `if ... elseif ... elseif ...` thing. I don't know what this is supposed to do though. I think his will always echo `$array[0]` so it could be simplified a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to pass an array containing a variable number of arrays, and select one of these at random. Is that correct?

If so, then this should do it:

```
$key = array_rand ($array);
$member = $array[$key];
```

No need to test for existence of members, as they will always exist. In fact as you can see, there isn't a need for creating a custom function at all. ;)

Comment: `array_rand` returns an array _key_.